# Why are refs as elements of a reactive array not unwrapped?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

**tl;dr** *The [official documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#caveat-in-arrays-and-collections) states that reactive elements of an array as element of a reactive object don't get unwrapped automatically. **Why?***

I am currently working on a restart for our several years old data processing engine and I wanted to offload most of its features to the amazing reactivity code of Vue3. The state of implementation is working well and a probable result could be simulated for illustration like this:

```js
const data = reactive( { a: 5, b: 6 } );
const view = reactive( {
  sum: computed( () => data.a + data.b ),
  list: [ computed( () => data.a + data.b ) ],
} );
```

According to the linked statement, I can access `view.sum` to get the `Number` 11 due to all properties of reactive object `view` are deeply unwrapped automatically. However, when accessing `view.list[0]`, I don't get the `Number` 11, but a `ref` with its value property providing the `Number` 11.

I struggle to get the reason for that behavior and the documentation isn't even trying to explain this caveat either.

In the mentioned engine, such heterogenous data is a problem and hence I was trying to fix it myself by putting the array into another `Proxy`.

```js
const handler = {
  get( target, property ) {
    switch ( typeof property ) {
      case "string" :
      case "number" :
        if ( /^[-+]?\d+$/.test( property ) ) {
          return unref( target[Number( property )] );
        }

        // falls through
      default :
        return target[property];
    }
  }
};

const data = reactive( { a: 5, b: 6 } );
const view = reactive( {
  sum: computed( () => data.a + data.b ),
  list: new Proxy( [ computed( () => data.a + data.b ) ], handler ),
} );
```

The resulting reactive object is working as expected:

- `Array.isArray( view.list )` is true.
- `view.list[0]` delivers the `Number` 11.
- If I changed `data.a` or `data.b`, `view.list[0]` is updated instantly.
- I can create another `computed` consuming `view.list[0]` and it gets triggered when changing either `data.a` or `data.b`, too.
- I can extract `view.list[0]` as a `ref` using `toRef()` with a getter function and `watch()` it for changes properly.
- Same works directly on `view.list[0]` with `watchEffect()`.

What am I missing? Why isn't Vue3 doing it like this right away?

Answer (score 0):

That's really a good question,and I found the answer took a few hours when I was ready to give up. I add some notes in the function createSetter from vue source code,you can checked it first, and there is a important logic that vue wants to **keep responsiveness between a ref and a reactive contains ref**.
**Next**,let's look at an example below just imitating vue reactive, the set function is triggered three times when we do 'data.unshift(2)', the first time,the value of data[1] changes from undefined to the Ref,and the second time, the value of data[0] changes from the Ref to 2, according to the vue theory above, the Ref will be synchronous modifyied, and this is certainly not logical, this bug Appearing because array has lots of modified functions like splice,unshift ,so this is the difference between array and object,and **vue need .value to keep responsiveness when a ref in an array**.
**Finally**,you may find my example used a ref not a computed, yes,  but there is another bug that the computed's value cant be modified by itself when data[0] changes from the Ref to 2.

```js
// Vue source code
function createSetter(shallow = false) {
  return function set2(target, key, value, receiver) {
    //  get the old value
    let oldValue = target[key];
    if (isReadonly(oldValue) && isRef(oldValue) && !isRef(value)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!shallow) {
      if (!isShallow(value) && !isReadonly(value)) {
        oldValue = toRaw(oldValue);
        value = toRaw(value);
      }
      if (!isArray(target) && isRef(oldValue) && !isRef(value)) {
        // if the old value is a ref and the target is Object , the old value will be synchronous modifyied
        oldValue.value = value;
        return true;
      }

      ...
    }
  }

  // example
  const data = reactive([ref(10)])
  data.unshift(2)

  function reactive(target) {
    const handler = {
      get(t, p) {
        return t[p]
      },
      set(t, p, v) {
        console.log(t, p, v)
        t[p] = v
        return true
      }
    }
    return new Proxy(target, handler)
  }

  // the console log
  [RefImpl]  '1'  RefImpl 
  [RefImpl, RefImpl]  '0'  2
  [2, RefImpl]  'length'  2
```

Comment: Indeed, adjusting the array is causing some oddities resulting in loss of reactivity. My presented use cases aren't covering those, yet.

Frankly, your description is hard to follow. AFAICS your excerpt of Vue source code isn't related to reactive arrays at all. At best, it's simply presenting the pattern in question rather than explaining why it's implemented there. In addition, as you've illustrated, unshifting items is causing three adjustments no matter the way Vue3 is dealing with reactive arrays. Hence it's unrelated.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good,I have tried my best to explain why vue dont unref a ref in  array .